# What's the difference between shǐ yòng 使用 and yòng 用？

Tags: word-choice, difference

Both mean to use. However, sometimes you need both and sometimes you can simply say yòng 用.

Examples:

謝謝你`使用`拼音 , thank you for using pinyin

謝謝你`用`鉛筆 , thank you for using a pencil

Comment: Cross-posted to [Reddit r/ChineseLanguage](https://www.reddit.com/r/ChineseLanguage/comments/fv7pn6/difference_between_sh%C7%90_y%C3%B2ng_%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8_and_y%C3%B2ng_%E7%94%A8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually they are almost the same just like in order to vs to have same effect.

But 用 can only be verb , can a little bit simplify the sentence .

使用 and 用 have same mean in below block

> 用水 用工具 用他的東西 用電腦
>
> 使用水 使用工具 使用他的東西 使用電腦
>
> use water ,use tools, use his stuff , use computer

使用 has more way to use.

> 使用手冊 使用時間 使用地點
>
> Operation Manual , usage time , Use location